# Fail to read remote property using Spring Cloud Consul

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, consul

We are planing to move the content of our numerous .properties files into Consul
I have implemented a demo with the following definition

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@RestController
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return env.getProperty("dc1/kv/property1/");
    } 
}
```

with the consul server running at the default

- localhost:8500
- data center name = DC1
- Node name = IT051080
- Service name = Consul-Demo
  I added a property manually from the web UI, it can be access from http://localhost:8500/ui/#/dc1/kv/property1

at moment `env.getProperty("dc1/kv/property1/");` **returns nothing**

my pom looks like this

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.SR6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

can anyone shed some lights please

Comment: Can you share bootstrap.yml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't reference properties like consul, you reference them like spring properties. By default, spring-cloud-consul looks under a `/config` context. Do you would need to put `property1` in `/config/property1` and reference it via `env.getProperty("property1")`. For `/config/foo/property` you would reference `foo.property` in spring's environment.

Comment: yes it worked also having the actual cloud-consul developer answering my question made my day! I am still not clear on the concept of profile in consul, if I create a property as /config/myApp,dev/property1 how can I read it from the Java Spring side? do I have to annotate my controller using @profile?

Comment: set `spring.profiles.active=dev`. `@Profile` is used to limit a configuration or component to only be created if that profile is active. See http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html